# When graphing residual error in R, how do I only show 1 graph on my R Markdown?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

Basically, I want to graph my residual error.

I have my linear regression line, say it's called "regline".

When I plot regline to get a graph of my residual error, I type:

```
plot(regline)
```

The problem is, I get 4 different graphs. Residuals vs. fitted, normal Q-Q, Scale-Location, Residuals vs. Leverage, but I only want the first one. I only want residuals vs. fitted. WHen I create an R Markdown, it  shows all 4. How can I make it so  that  wehen i  create an  R markdown, I only get Residuals vs. fitted, rather than all 4.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you can provide a minimal reproducible code example it will help other users understand and solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `?plot.lm`.

> which
>   if a subset of the plots is required, specify a subset of the numbers 1:6, see caption below (and the ‘Details’) for the different kinds.

So you want:

```
plot(regline, which = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I was looking for

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.